# XSLT numbering - grouping?

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to do the following:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <p> text<note/>texttext<note/>text </p>
        <p> text<note/>text </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        text<note/>texttext<note/>text
    </div>
</body>
```

should result in

```
<body>
    <div>
        <p> text<note n="1"/>texttext<note n="2"/>text </p>
        <p> text<note n="3"/>text </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        text<note n="1"/>texttext<note n="2"/>text
    </div>
</body>
```

As you can see, I want to number all notes under div regardless of the parent node. So notes can be structured under div in any way.
However I can't figure out a solution by using xsl:number. Any help would be appreciated.

edit: Big thanks to DRCB for his solution. I've adapted it so that it can be also used for complex nesting by using an identity template.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div//note">
    <note>
        <xsl:attribute name="n">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::note) - count(preceding::div//note) + 1"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </note>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

tranforms:

```
<body>
    <any>
        <div>
            <p>
                <p> text<note/>texttext<note/>text </p>
            </p>
            <p> text<note/>text </p>
        </div>
    </any>
    <div> text<note/>texttext<note/>text </div>
</body>
```

to:

```
<body>
    <any>
        <div>
            <p>
                <p> text<note n="1"/>texttext<note n="2"/>text </p>
            </p>
            <p> text<note n="3"/>text </p>
        </div>
    </any>
    <div> text<note n="1"/>texttext<note n="2"/>text </div>
</body>
```

I believe there might be a better solution however this works for me.

Comment: Try the solutions here: [XSLT increment variable][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770951/xslt-increment-variable

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer to your own question. Not edit it into the question itself.

Comment: I have to wait 24h before I can answer my own question. This is why I have edited the post.

Comment: @Chris: What about a simpler solution that just uses `xsl:number` ?  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A solution using `xsl:number`:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="note">
  <xsl:variable name="vNum">
   <xsl:number level="any" count="note" from="/*/div"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <note n="{$vNum}">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </note>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<body>
 <div>
  <p> text<note/>texttext<note/>text </p>
  <p> text<note/>text </p>
 </div>
 <div>
  text<note/>texttext<note/>text
 </div>
</body>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<body>
   <div>
      <p> text<note n="1"/>texttext<note n="2"/>text </p>
      <p> text<note n="3"/>text </p>
   </div>
   <div>
  text<note n="1"/>texttext<note n="2"/>text
 </div>
</body>
```

**Explanation**: Appropriate use of the `from` attribute of `xsl:number`.

Answer (score 1):

I have found following quick workaround:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalogp -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="div">
  [div <xsl:apply-templates/>]
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="note">
  [note n=<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::note) - count(preceding::div//note) + 1"/>]
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works however only with "plain" div structure without a complex nesting.

You can test it here: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog with your source xml.

Comment: Thank you. I'm currently trying to adapt your solution by using an identity template (i.e. match="node()|@*"). I think this could work so that it could also be used for complex nestings.